# Django error: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python, django

I have some problem with my code. I was looking have to solve it, but I didn't find similar problem. I want to multiple and then sum some field values, but I get error from a title. Have to solve this problem? I suppose that is problem with data type, but I don't know how to define equation. Please help me.

```
class Bill(models.Model):
   date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now())
   tax = models.FloatField(default=0.20)
   priceNoTax = models.IntegerField()#integer that I get from other class
   priceTax = models.FloatField()
   idAccount = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Account")

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if self.priceTax is None:
           self.priceTax = self.priceNoTax+(self.priceNoTax*self.tax)#here is an error
       super(Bill, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

   def __str__(self):
        return self.date
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You've checked if `priceTax` is None, but you haven't checked if `priceNoTax` is None, which it apparently is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the arguments in the error message corresponds to the code:

`'NoneType' and 'float'` <=> `self.priceNoTax*self.tax`

`self.priceNoTax` has not been initialised, or if you loaded this from the database then it contained `NULL`. You can verify this with a `print` of the contents of `self.priceNoTax` on the line before the multiplication takes place.

Double check how `self.priceNoTax` is being set.